# Transform a section within a nested Json in a Pandas dataframe column into another dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a Pandas dataframe where I find this Json in a column:

```
quote
{'BTC': {'price': 1, 'volume_24h': 1e-08, 'percent_change_1h': 0, 'percent_change_24h': 0, 'percent_change_7d': 0, 'market_cap': 11071985.881444559, 'fully_diluted_market_cap': None, 'last_updated': '2013-04-29T00:00:01.000Z'}, 'USD': {'price': 134.210021972656, 'volume_24h': 0, 'percent_change_1h': 0.639231, 'percent_change_24h': None, 'percent_change_7d': None, 'market_cap': 1488566971.9558687, 'last_updated': '2013-04-28T23:55:01.000Z'}}
{'BTC': {'price': 0.032343507812039, 'volume_24h': 1e-08, 'percent_change_1h': 0.799273, 'percent_change_24h': None, 'percent_change_7d': None, 'market_cap': 555151.4070926482, 'fully_diluted_market_cap': None, 'last_updated': '2013-04-29T00:00:01.000Z'}, 'USD': {'price': 4.34840488433838, 'volume_24h': 0, 'percent_change_1h': 0.799273, 'percent_change_24h': None, 'percent_change_7d': None, 'market_cap': 74637021.56790735, 'last_updated': '2013-04-28T23:55:01.000Z'}}
{'BTC': {'price': 0.002874978304697, 'volume_24h': 1e-08, 'percent_change_1h': -0.934763, 'percent_change_24h': None, 'percent_change_7d': None, 'market_cap': 53927.00880335152, 'fully_diluted_market_cap': None, 'last_updated': '2013-04-29T00:00:01.000Z'}, 'USD': {'price': 0.38652485609054604, 'volume_24h': 0, 'percent_change_1h': -0.934763, 'percent_change_24h': None, 'percent_change_7d': None, 'market_cap': 7250186.647688276, 'last_updated': '2013-04-28T23:55:03.000Z'}}
{'BTC': {'price': 0.008235615152382001, 'volume_24h': 1e-08, 'percent_change_1h': -0.0505028, 'percent_change_24h': None, 'percent_change_7d': None, 'market_cap': 44598.326734696995, 'fully_diluted_market_cap': None, 'last_updated': '2013-04-29T00:00:01.000Z'}, 'USD': {'price': 1.10723268985748, 'volume_24h': 0, 'percent_change_1h': -0.0505028, 'percent_change_24h': None, 'percent_change_7d': None, 'market_cap': 5995997.185385211, 'last_updated': '2013-04-28T23:55:02.000Z'}}
{'BTC': {'price': 0.004811595748858, 'volume_24h': 1e-08, 'percent_change_1h': 0.609159, 'percent_change_24h': None, 'percent_change_7d': None, 'market_cap': 11180.078331276067, 'fully_diluted_market_cap': None, 'last_updated': '2013-04-29T00:00:01.000Z'}, 'USD': {'price': 0.646892309188843, 'volume_24h': 0, 'percent_change_1h': 0.609159, 'percent_change_24h': None, 'percent_change_7d': None, 'market_cap': 1503099.4011388426, 'last_updated': '2013-04-28T23:55:02.000Z'}}
{'BTC': {'price': 2.425762856e-06, 'volume_24h': 1e-08, 'percent_change_1h': 0.461694, 'percent_change_24h': None, 'percent_change_7d': None, 'market_cap': 10592.384991552675, 'fully_diluted_market_cap': None, 'last_updated': '2013-04-29T00:00:01.000Z'}, 'USD': {'price': 0.00032613033545200005, 'volume_24h': 0, 'percent_change_1h': 0.461694, 'percent_change_24h': None, 'percent_change_7d': None, 'market_cap': 1424087.2975724188, 'last_updated': '2013-04-28T23:55:14.000Z'}}
{'BTC': {'price': 0.03158483190407, 'volume_24h': 1e-08, 'percent_change_1h': 2.13819, 'percent_change_24h': None, 'percent_change_7d': None, 'market_cap': 8644.956027083475, 'fully_diluted_market_cap': None, 'last_updated': '2013-04-29T00:00:01.000Z'}, 'USD': {'price': 4.24640512466431, 'volume_24h': 0, 'percent_change_1h': 2.13819, 'percent_change_24h': None, 'percent_change_7d': None, 'market_cap': 1162266.2956510494, 'last_updated': '2013-04-28T23:55:03.000Z'}}
Name: quote, dtype: object
```

How can i do through Pandas to transform this dataframe column containing Json into an ordered dataframe?
I am interested in the part of the data in the USD section

I tried using `"pd.json_normalize"` but I can't get any changes.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(df['quote'].tolist())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your JSON is nested, you will get only 2 columns of the highest level sections `BTC` and `USD` even when we expand the JSON into dataframe. As such, we have to specifically get access to the part of the data you are interested first, i.e. the `USD` section.

Optional Step: in case your column `quote` is a string instead of real JSON, you can first convert the string to real JSON first, as below.  Otherwise, just skip this step:

```
import ast
df['quote'] = df['quote'].map(ast.literal_eval)
```

After ensuring your column `quote` is of real JSON, rather than string, to get access of the `USD` section, we can use the string accessor `str[]`, as follows:

```
df['quote'].str['USD']
```

(We can skip this step and run the last step. Here, just run to ensure you get the contents of the required section)

This will give:

```
0    {'price': 134.210021972656, 'volume_24h': 0, '...
1    {'price': 4.34840488433838, 'volume_24h': 0, '...
2    {'price': 0.38652485609054604, 'volume_24h': 0...
3    {'price': 1.10723268985748, 'volume_24h': 0, '...
4    {'price': 0.646892309188843, 'volume_24h': 0, ...
5    {'price': 0.00032613033545200005, 'volume_24h'...
6    {'price': 4.24640512466431, 'volume_24h': 0, '...
Name: quote, dtype: object
```

Then, to access its contents (i.e USD section) and expand into separate columns, we can use:

```
pd.DataFrame(df['quote'].str['USD'].tolist())
```

**Result:**

```
        price  volume_24h  percent_change_1h percent_change_24h percent_change_7d    market_cap              last_updated
0  134.210022           0           0.639231               None              None  1.488567e+09  2013-04-28T23:55:01.000Z
1    4.348405           0           0.799273               None              None  7.463702e+07  2013-04-28T23:55:01.000Z
2    0.386525           0          -0.934763               None              None  7.250187e+06  2013-04-28T23:55:03.000Z
3    1.107233           0          -0.050503               None              None  5.995997e+06  2013-04-28T23:55:02.000Z
4    0.646892           0           0.609159               None              None  1.503099e+06  2013-04-28T23:55:02.000Z
5    0.000326           0           0.461694               None              None  1.424087e+06  2013-04-28T23:55:14.000Z
6    4.246405           0           2.138190               None              None  1.162266e+06  2013-04-28T23:55:03.000Z
```